# Is this a known result?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I heard the following result and I am wondering if anyone can verify its correctness and also provide a source to cite.

If the Lagrangian $L(x,\lambda)$ is convex in $x$ at the optimal Lagrange multiplier $\lambda^*$, that is, $L(x,\lambda^*)$ is convex in $x$, then the KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient for optimality.

Comment: It is not clear what is meant by the "optimal Lagrange multiplier," particularly for nonconvex problems.  Also, the derivative conditions for KKT cannot hold in cases where the function is convex but not differentiable.  So, it is not clear what KKT conditions you want to consider, or under what assumptions you want your statement to hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You at least need differentiability for existence of KKT. But if you focus on sufficiency, you can say this:

*Sufficiency:*

Suppose your problem is to minimize $f(x)$ over a convex set $X$ and subject to $g_k(x)\leq 0$ for all $k \in \{1, \ldots, K\}$ (call this Probelm P1). Define: 
$$ L(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \sum_{k=1}^K\lambda_k g_k(x) $$
Assume that $\lambda^*$ is a vector with nonnegative components.  Assume that $L(x,\lambda^*)$ is a convex function over $x \in X$.  Assume we have a vector $x^* \in X$ for which the following "KKT conditions" hold: 
\begin{align} 
&\nabla f(x^*) + \sum_{k=1}^K \lambda_k^* \nabla g_k(x^*) = 0 \\
& g_k(x^*) \leq 0 \: \: \forall k \in \{1, \ldots, K\} \\
&\lambda_k^* \geq 0 \: \: \forall k \in \{1, \ldots, K\} \\
&\lambda_k^*g_k(x^*) = 0 \: \: \forall k \in \{1, \ldots, K\} 
\end{align} 
We want to show that $x^*$ is an optimal solution to the problem P1. The above assumptions show that $x^*$ satisfies the constraints (namely, $x^* \in X$ and $g_k(x^*) \leq 0$ for all $k \in \{1, \ldots, K\}$).  The derivative assumptions also show that $x^*$ is a point of zero-derivative for the function $L(x, \lambda^*)$. Since this function is convex in $x$, $x^*$ must minimize $L(x,\lambda^*)$ over all $x \in X$. Thus, for all $x \in X$ we have: 
$$ L(x^*,\lambda^*) \leq L(x,\lambda^*) $$
That is, for all $x \in X$: 
$$ f(x^*) + \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^K\lambda_k^*g_k(x^*)}_{zero} \leq f(x) + \sum_{k=1}^K\lambda_k^*g_k(x) $$ 
Thus, if $x$ is a vector in $X$ that satisfies the constraints $g_k(x) \leq 0$ for all $k$, then $\sum_{k=1}^K\lambda_k^*g_k(x) \leq 0$ (recall that $\lambda_k^*\geq 0$ for all $k$) and the above inequality reduces to $f(x^*) \leq f(x)$, meaning that $x^*$ is an optimal solution to problem P1.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the above holds for an equality (no inequality constraints) constrained problem as well? That is, define the Lagrangian as $\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_ih_i(x)$ where $h_i(x) = 0$, $i=1,\ldots,m$ are the constraints. I think it should still hold but I'm getting a bit stuck.